# Modificar objeto dentro de otro objeto Typescript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, javascript-objeto, sequelize.js

Me encuentro modificando un sistema de envio de whatsapp. En este caso, lo que necesitaria hacer es que se agreguen etiquetas a cada contacto. Para esto, tengo el modelado de las 3 entidades, con su relacion mucho a mucho hacia la tabla userTags.
Pero, al ser una modificación y no tener mucha experiencia en esta forma de trabajar, no entiendo como deberia modificar el servicio de Update, para que si se asocia un nuevo Tag para el contacto, se guarde en base de datos.

en el archivo updateContactService.ts tengo tags que sería el nuevo array de objetos tags, y ademas antes hago un findOne para encontrar el contacto con su array de tags correspondiente.

Se les ocurre una idea? o al menos, se les ocurre por donde puedo empezar a leer o googlear acerca de esta forma de codigo? Gracias!

Modelo Contacto:

```
lass Contact extends Model<Contact> {
@PrimaryKey
@AutoIncrement
@Column
id: number;

@Column
name: string;

@AllowNull(false)
@Unique
@Column
number: string;

@AllowNull(false)
@Default("")
@Column
email: string;

@Column
profilePicUrl: string;

@Default(false)
@Column
isGroup: boolean;

@CreatedAt
createdAt: Date;

@UpdatedAt
updatedAt: Date;

@HasMany(() => Ticket)
tickets: Ticket[];

@HasMany(() => ContactCustomField)
extraInfo: ContactCustomField[];

@BelongsToMany(() => Tags, { as: "tags", through: () => UserTags})
tags: Tags[];
```

Modelo Tags

```
  class Tags extends Model<Tags> {
@PrimaryKey
@AutoIncrement
@Column
id: number;

@AllowNull(false)
@Unique
@Column
name: string;

@AllowNull(false)
@Unique
@Column
color: string;

@CreatedAt
createdAt: Date;

@UpdatedAt
updatedAt: Date;

@BelongsToMany(() => Contact, () => UserTags)
contact: Contact[];
```

}

Modelo UserTags (tagId y contactoId)

```
  class UserTags extends Model<UserTags> {
@ForeignKey(() => Contact)
@Column
contactId: number;

@ForeignKey(() => Tags)
@Column
tagsId: number;

@CreatedAt
createdAt: Date;

@UpdatedAt
updatedAt: Date;
```

}

UpdateContactService.ts

```
import AppError from "../../errors/AppError";
import Contact from "../../models/Contact";
import Tags from "../../models/Tags";
import ContactCustomField from "../../models/ContactCustomField";
import UserTags from "../../models/UserTags";

interface ExtraInfo {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  value: string;
}
interface ContactData {
  email?: string;
  number?: string;
  name?: string;
  extraInfo?: ExtraInfo[];
  tags?: Tags[];

}

interface Request {
  contactData: ContactData;
  contactId: string;
}

const UpdateContactService = async ({
  contactData,
  contactId
}: Request): Promise<Contact> => {
  const { email, name, number, extraInfo, tags } = contactData;

  const contact = await Contact.findOne({
    where: { id: contactId },
    attributes: ["id", "name", "number", "email", "profilePicUrl"],
    include: ["extraInfo", "tags"]
  });

  if (!contact) {
    throw new AppError("ERR_NO_CONTACT_FOUND", 404);
  }

  if (extraInfo) {
    await Promise.all(
      extraInfo.map(async info => {
        await ContactCustomField.upsert({ ...info, contactId: contact.id });
      })
    );

    await Promise.all(
      contact.extraInfo.map(async oldInfo => {
        const stillExists = extraInfo.findIndex(info => info.id === oldInfo.id);

        if (stillExists === -1) {
          await ContactCustomField.destroy({ where: { id: oldInfo.id } });
        }
      })
    );
  }


  await contact.update({
    name,
    number,
    email
  });

  await contact.reload({
    attributes: ["id", "name", "number", "email", "profilePicUrl"],
    include: ["extraInfo", {
      model: Tags,
      as: "tags",
      attributes: ["name"]
    }]
  });

  return contact;
};

export default UpdateContactService;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví creando una ruta y un servicio aparte que se encargue de añadir y otra que se encargue de eliminar el tag para el usuario.